# Unable to Edit top 200 rows in SQL Server Management Studio 2014(X64)

Tags: sql-server

I am unable to edit top 200 rows in SQL Server. Everytime I click edit top 200 rows I receive this message and sql server restarts. [image]

I have tried to reinstall SQL Server management and also tried to

– Copy and replace the DLL “dsref80.dll” in below path from a machine where SSMS is working fine in to the machine where the problem exists.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Visual Database Tools\dsref80.dll
– Replace all the files in below folder using the files from another server where SSMS is working fine.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8\
– Close and Open SSMS.

None of these solutions seem to work

Comment: There have been many bugs reported over the years of using the Edit top 200. It would probably be a good idea to just write your updates in a query window. Once you get used to it you will find it is much faster too.

Comment: I usually do write my own updates but its bugging me that I cant use edit top 200

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue and found the reason:
I was connecting to a SQL Server 2014 database using SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

Installing and using SQL Server Management Studio 2014 rectified the problem.

It appears that they are not compatible. Though it should be noted that I didn't have any service packs installed for either version.

Answer (score 1):

Did you recently install multiple .NET Framework applications and MS software? If so, you might need to reset your network adapter.

Try running the following command in CMD (Run as Administrator):

```
netsh winsock reset
```

**--- Update ---**

Are you updated to the latest SQL Server 2014 SP?

Check your version by using this SQL statement:

```
USE master
SELECT @@version
```

The latest version is `SQL Server 2014 SP2 (12.0.5000.0 – July 2016)`.

Comment: It is possible I have installed multiple .net framework apps this hasn't been working for me for a month now I just tried resetting winsock same issue occurs.

Comment: Yes I restarted my PC as well.

Comment: Im on Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64)  not seeing a way to update if you could help me out @10100111001

Comment: @Arron In your post title you mentioned SSMS 2014

Comment: Sorry im on my work pc and its happening here as well which is leading me to believe its something I installed which just started happening here **Correction** This is only happening on Localdb working fine on a production db

Comment: @Arron Download this update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3164398

Comment: Same issue :( I appreciate all your effort btw!

Comment: So instead of using (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB I used (Localdb)\v11.0 and it works fine now